# How to get the length of the compressed data from DeflateStream?

Tags: c#, memorystream, deflatestream

The following is a simple compression method I wrote using `DeflateStream`:

```
public static int Compress(
    byte[] inputData, 
    int inputStartIndex, 
    int inputLength, 
    byte[] outputData, 
    int outputStartIndex, 
    int outputLength)
{
    if (inputData == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("inputData must be non-null");

    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(outputData, outputStartIndex, outputLength);

    using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(memStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
    {
        dstream.Write(inputData, inputStartIndex, inputLength);
        return (int)(memStream.Position - outputStartIndex);
    }
}
```

What is special in this method is that I didn't use the parameter-less constructor of `MemoryStream`. This is because it is a high-throughput server. Array `outputData` is rented from `ArrayPool`, to be used to hold the compressed bytes, so that after I make use of it I can return it to `ArrayPool`.

The compression happened properly, and the compressed data is properly placed into `outputData`, but `memStream.Position` was zero, so I can't find out how many bytes have been written into the `MemoryStream`.

Only part of `outputData` is occupied by the compressed data. How do I find out the length of the compressed data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MemoryStream.Position` is 0 because data was not actually written there yet at the point you read `Position`. Instead, tell `DeflateStream` to leave underlying stream (`MemoryStream`) open, then dispose `DeflateStream`. At this point you can be sure it's done writing whatever it needs. Now you can read `MemoryStream.Position` to check how many bytes were written:

```
public static int Compress(
    byte[] inputData, 
    int inputStartIndex, 
    int inputLength, 
    byte[] outputData, 
    int outputStartIndex, 
    int outputLength)
{
    if (inputData == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("inputData must be non-null");

    using (var memStream = new MemoryStream(outputData, outputStartIndex, outputLength)) {

        // leave open
        using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(memStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, leaveOpen: true)) {
            dstream.Write(inputData, inputStartIndex, inputLength);
        }

        return (int) memStream.Position; // now it's not 0
    }
}
```

You also don't need to substract `outputStartIndex`, because `Position` is already relative to that index you passed to constructor.